# Protractor get Window offset can get information

Tags: window, jasmine, protractor

I am running a test where i click some navigation button,

I need to check the page scrolls down correctly.

But i can get protractor to use the native window offset where you can see if a page has been scrolled.

Has anyway got an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet

Comment: @liquified no sorry never got round to looking at it again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the visibility checking in Protractor do to this. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf

From the example on the page:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
```

Comment: Will that work, if the element is on the page but of of view by scroll?

Comment: I believe so. If the element is in the DOM but not shown on the page (the page needs to be scrolled either way before the element is shown) then it is not visible. You could also try checking to see if the element is clickable with http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable

Comment: I'm confused he asked to get the window offset to verify the page was scrolled, not if the element was visible?

Comment: Because offset isn't what would solve the issue, element visibility is.